# Perl if Statement only specific length of numbers

Tags: perl, if-statement, numbers, integer

is it possible to have an if-statement where I look if my $expression has less than 12 integers and only integers. Like
if($expression> less than 12numbers and only integers).

Comment: Do you mean `digits` by `integer`?

Comment: @Amomamokhan Could you please provide input string/expression for the same. So that it would be easier for people to answer instead of guessing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match it using regex. Below is the code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $exp = "1234567898711";

if ($exp =~ /^\d{12}$/) {
    say "Matched expression: $exp";
} else {
    say "Not matched";
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to look for 12 digits or less than that use below expression:

```
\d{1,12}
```

Note: This expression is only when you have straight digits. If its a alphanumeric, then it needed to be changed accordingly.

Comment: it must be exactly 12 digits with only numbers.

Comment: Note that if you want only ASCII digits, you can use [the /a flag](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/12/enforce-ascii-semantics-when-you-only-want-ascii/) or the character class `[0-9]`. The `\d` shortcut matches hundreds of characters.

Comment: @Amomamokhan Good to know. Thanks in SO would be given using upvote/accept :)